Non-async function call inside an async function
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function Form() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  function sleep(milliseconds) {
    const start = Date.now();
    while (Date.now() - start < milliseconds) {
    }
  }

  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    sleep(5000);
  }

  function handleTextareaChange(e) {
    setText(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Test</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <textarea
          value={text}
          onChange={handleTextareaChange}
        />
        <br />
        <button>
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}

I edited this component from the react docs to make it to the point.
I was learning react and JavaScript and ran into async functions in the react docs.
Here when I submit the form I can not edit it until the sleep runs out, but my confusion is that the sleep(5000) was called inside an async function.
Calling functions inside async functions does not make them non-blocking?
Or, does the form also call await on the handleSubmit as well?
My knowledge on JavaScript and react is low, so I may not be using terms correctly.

javascript is "single threaded" ... nothing else can run while your naive sleep function is in the while loop - i.e. your sleep function is blocking, regardless of what calls it

To understand async function. You should start at Promise because async function is just syntax for create promise. In the second link there is example for proper sleep function.

What is the purpose of that sleep call? In your code it doesn't seem to serve any purpose.

"Calling functions inside async functions does not make them non-blocking?" - yes, it doesn't. All an async does is to allow using await with promises.

Just because a function is called inside an async function, it doesn't automatically make that function non-blocking. The function itself needs to be asynchronous or involve an asynchronous operation (like await or Promise-based operations) to avoid blocking.
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
}

async function handleSubmit() {
  await sleep(5000); // Non-blocking now because it's asynchronous
  // other logic
}



Calling functions inside async functions does not make them non-blocking?

Just moving a function to a different place in the code does not reduce the amount of work that the Javascript engine has to do. And while it does the work, its single thread is still blocked. Asynchronous functions are useful if they communicate with other systems (fetch from a web server, select from a database, await user input, and so on), because the Javascript engine can do other work while waiting for the other system to respond.
Waiting for 5000ms can be viewed as a special case of communication with another system, if it is implemented with setTimeout: in this case the "other system" is the system clock.
The "other system" can also be a second thread of the same Javascript engine (a worker thread in a browser, or a second Node.js process as in Expressjs main loop blocked during intense operation).

As you know, there are synchronous codes and asynchronous codes.
For example, the below statement is synchronous. It will block execution of the main function until it finishes. Please see the output below.
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  console.log('sleeping');
  const start = Date.now();
  while (Date.now() - start < milliseconds) {}
}

sleep();
console.log('main function');

Output
sleeping
main function

However, the below statement is asynchronous, although it does not wait for even 1 millisecond. Please see the output, the main function logs before the sleep function.
setTimeout(() => sleep(), 0);
console.log('main function');

Output
main function
sleeping

What has been essentially happened in the above code is that we could write a synchronous statement executed in asynchronous manner.
Now when we need to do the opposite, to write an asynchronous code in synchronous manner, how do we do it ? This is where the async - await keyword pair applies.
In the code below, although the second asynchronous statement is timed out in 1 second, that statement still waits for the completion of the first asynchronous statement which finishes later in 2 seconds. It means that we could write two asynchronous statements to execute in synchronous manner. Please see below the output.
async function asyncfunc() {
  await new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(1);
      sleep();
      console.log('slept for 2000ms');
    }, 2000)
  );
  await new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(1);
      sleep();
      console.log('slept for 1000ms');
    }, 1000)
  );
}

asyncfunc().then(() => {});
console.log('main function');

Output
main function
sleeping
slept for 2000ms
sleeping
slept for 1000ms

The summary is that the code needs to be asynchronous in nature to get it executed in async manner. In the above examples, setTimeout is the asynchronous function which makes the synchronous code asynchronous. A synchronous code enclosed in a function with async keyword does not make the function executed asynchronously.
However, the asynchronous statements enclosed in a function with async-await keyword pair makes the function to execute the asynchronous calls synchronously  and execute the function as a whole still asynchronously. Please recall that in the above output, main function finishes earlier than the async function.
